# Error in ARIMA function in R

Tags: r, arima, error-message, automatic-algorithms

I am analyzing time series data with `'Arima'` function in R. 
As you know, to find optimum model, I have tried lots of cases. 
But, I am tired of finding and analyzing cases in person. 
So, I decided to run it automatically. 
And I made a command(or algorithm. whatever.) and ran it. But, I confront with this problem.

```
"Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]"
```

What's the problem with my command?

Here is my command.

---

```
result=matrix(NA,144,2)
ari<-0
num<-1

for(i in 0:5){
for(j in 0:5){
for(k in 0:1){
for(l in 0:1){

ari<-Arima(dcall,c(i,0,j),season=list(order=c(k,1,l),period=96))
result[num,1]<-ari$aic
result[num,2]<-ari$aicc
num<-num+1

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I used 'forecast' library

Comment: You certainly did'nt use a *library*, you used a *package*! A *library* is a collection of *package*s. Would you say you "read it in the library"? It would be more useful to specify in which book!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, there must be a reason why `library(forecast)` is used to load the package "forecast" :) You could also say a book is a collection of pages and rant if someone explained he read it in a book without stating the page number :) But honestly, you could be right, I do not know enough about these conventions.

Comment: > library(fortunes)
> fortune("library")

(3 times...rrrrgh...) and why do you think the mailing list is called
R-*packages* ???????????
Please do
  for(i in 1:20) cat("It's a package!\n")
   -- Martin Maechler (after a newly released *package* has been called
      *library* three times in its announcement on R-packages)
      R-help (March 2006)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like your model explodes, or rather has infinite derivation somewhere in the solver (non-finite finite difference value). 
What is the setup it crashes with? (you could have for instance printed the values)

Comment: Thanks to you, I found that yes, model explodes. Then, I have a new question. I found that when one model explodes, the algorithm stopped. So all the other model behind explode model didn't run. How can I fix it? How can I run all the model ignoring explode model?

Comment: Use `try(Arima(...))` to catch the error and continue the for loop.

Comment: yh or you can try `auto.arima`in `forecast` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf) it is most likely going to handle the divergence itself :)